# How to get ngOptions to select an option based on model propery value while ignoring case?

Tags: angularjs

I have a static list of states:

```
 $scope.states = [
                   { name: 'Alaska', code: 'AK'},
                   { name: 'Alabama', code: 'AL'},
                   ..........
                   ]
```

and a dropdown

```
<select name="state" ng-model="vm.customer.state" ng-options="s.name
 as s.name for s in vm.states">
   <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

The only time when the downdrop selects the customer's state is when the customer's state matches the value in the list. So if the state is 'Alaska', Alaska is shown but if it's alaska or alAska.. etc, it's blank.

How do I make the binding case insensitive without changing the model value/case?

Comment: Where is the customer state selection being set originally?  You are leaving out some details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could `$watch` the model itself and format it so it correspond to the item values:

```
$scope.$watch('customer.state', function(newVal) {
  if (newVal) {
    $scope.customer.state = newVal.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + newVal.toLowerCase().slice(1)
  }
})
```

Updates alabama to Alabama, ALABAMA to Alabama etc.